# Can parallel insert statements in sql lead to deadlock?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am having a SP that is doing a select union of many tables with no lock. This will do lot of calculations with many groupings and sumation and so will take about 2 min for its run. I need to run this for about 500 different set of data. So It totally takes about 1000 min.

To reduce this I need to run this calculation in parallel. So if i run for 4 set of data in parallel I should be done in about 250 min.

But the problem is that once i am done with this calculations I get a set of data that i need to store into a table which has some primary key constraints on 4 of its columns. So when running in parallel I am expecting some dead lock issues. So I was thinking of writing this data to a temporary table that will have the same columns but with no primary key or any constraints.

So with this I am expecting there should be no dead lock. Please advice in this regards and let me know if my understanding is right. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INSERT` cannot deadlock against another `INSERT` on the same table, because two `INSERT` statement on the same table will always acquire the locks in the same order. That being said, I must comment on your statement:

> > if i run for 4 set of data in parallel I should be done in about 250 min.

You have no reason to expect this. First and foremost such a claim denotes you ignore [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law). Second a SQL workload is *already* parallelism internally, the queries in your procedure use parallel plans whenever possible, see [Parallel Query Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178065.aspx), *especially* if it contains many 'groupings and summations'.

Ultimately what you're facing is an optimization task. Approach it like any other optimization task, identify the bottlenecks first. [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) is a must read as you embark this journey.