# How to run more than one query at a time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to generate a big report consists of 45 insert statements. How can I Run more than one insert statement at a time it by splitting the queries into groups.

Comment: I assume you mean "in parallel", given your comment to one question below. You should update your question accordingly to avoid confusion. Also you might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9799283/21567) answer to a related question. You might not gain a lot by making the inserts run in parallel.

Comment: @Candy what are you trying to achieve?  Faster inserts?  Batched inserts?  Also, why are you inserting for a report?  Are you generating some form of temp structure as a part of your report?  Some more context will help us get to the root of your problem.

Comment: @Gibron I need to make the transaction faster, i think that If we run more than one query at a time,the total time of the query execution will be minimized

Comment: @Christian, Yes, I mean "in parallel"

Answer (score 1):

USe Stored Procedure for that and by using it u can return value also.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It is already a stored procedure.Now using the timestamp i can find that every insert statement is executed one by one. Is there any chance to make into groups like, I will execute 1-10 reports and at the same time 11-20,21-30... will also be executed

Comment: Query is groups are referring to similar table or or of same behaviour.

Comment: I am planning to group the query by considering the table it uses. say, If I use Calendar table for more than one query, I will group the insert statements related to Calendar table

Comment: Which language u are using for front end. if u are using java or .net then call all groups using thread so all query no parallel but partially parallelisms u can achieve. grpup1-->one stored procedure-->one thread. and if dependency is the key issue then you can do that also with that.

Comment: This is a stored procedure. I am not using any front end tool. Can we split this stored procedure to two or more and run in parallal

Answer (score 0):

You can write 45 insert statements in stored procedure.

Comment: They will not be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You might succeed in running multiple sessions (i.e. logins).[EDIT] I wrote, that an insert locks the table, which is wrong. Thanks @marc_s. [/EDIT]

However, if your `insert` precedes a complex query, you might be successful, as the queries could be carried out in parallel.

But, it greatly depends on the code.

Isn't there anything you can improve using the existing code? Usually, there is enough room for a performance boost just by looking at the statements.

Comment: Inserts will lock the **newly inserted row** - not necessarily the whole table!

Answer (score 0):

Try using multiple stored procedures where each stored procedure handles several insert statement. Even if you execute these procedures one by one they should be executed in parallel on SQL server as long as you’re using different connections.